# Enterprise wsdl login shows 'Access Denied' in SoapUI

Tags: soap-api, login-errors, enterprise-wsdl

I am using SoapUI to test Enterprise wsdl login. I have entered username and password correctly. But still I receive error in the Response as 'Access Denied (Authentication Failed)' .

I have excluded Organization ID as an input parameter. The Enterprise wsdl is from my sandbox environment. I do not have the security token also.

I am getting no clue as how to resolve this. Any help is highly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Below is the ,
Request:-

   
      
        
         
         
      
   
   
      
         xxxxxxxxxx
         xxxxxxxxxx

Response XML:-

   Access Denied

> Access Denied (authentication_failed)
>    
>    
>    
>    
>    
>    
>    Your credentials could not be authenticated: "Credentials are missing.". You will not be permitted access until your credentials can be verified.
>    
>    
>    
>    
>    This is typically caused by an incorrect username and/or password, but could also be caused by network problems.
>    
>    
>    
>    
>    
>    For assistance, contact your network support team.

**Response RAW:**

```
HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
Proxy-Authenticate: NEGOTIATE
Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
Proxy-Authenticate: BASIC realm="xxxxxxx"
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Proxy-Connection: close
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1029
<HTML><HEAD>
   <TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
   <FONT face="Helvetica">
   <big><strong></strong></big><BR>
   </FONT>
   <blockquote>
   <TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
   <TR><TD>
   <FONT face="Helvetica">
   <big>Access Denied (authentication_failed)</big>
   <BR>
   <BR>
   </FONT>
   </TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>
   <FONT face="Helvetica">
```

**Your credentials could not be authenticated:**

"Credentials are missing.". You will not be permitted access until your credentials can be verified.

```
  </FONT>
   </TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>
   <FONT face="Helvetica">
   This is typically caused by an incorrect username and/or password, but could also be caused by network problems.
   </FONT>
   </TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>
   <FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
   <BR>
   For assistance, contact your network support team.
   </FONT>
   </TD></TR>
   </TABLE>
   </blockquote>
   </FONT>
   </BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Request :- <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:LoginScopeHeader>
        <urn:organizationId></urn:organizationId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:portalId></urn:portalId>
      </urn:LoginScopeHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:login>
         <urn:username>xxx</urn:username>
         <urn:password>xxx</urn:password>
      </urn:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: You will have to provide the Security token along with the password. If you don't have security contact then reset the security token which will be sent to the email address set to your user. Also, can you try with whitelisting your IP address under Network Access?

Comment: I created a test user and attached it to a profile which has no IP restrictions. But I do not see Security Token anywhere. I had reset the password but still no security token arrived in the mail.